# compile turtlebot in groovy on gumstix

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-groovy, gumstix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello world,

I am trying to compile the turtlebot software from source on my gumstix. I do not really have a problem with it, I just want to know if I am doing it the right way, because it is a very slow way. I manually scroll through the dependencies for turtlebot, locate the source and check if I can compile it with catkin. Then I add it to wstool, download the source and catkin_make it. Since compiling on the gumstix is really slow, I am not done yet, but I would like to know if there is a smarter way. Maybe a way to resolve all dependencies and find out which sources are catkinized and which have to be built in the rosbuild workspace?
I also did not get PCL to compile :(

Thanks a lot in advance

Kai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51507/compile-turtlebot-in-groovy-on-gumstix/) by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the best way is to use the generator. It looks like it will only generate wet packages. So if you want to add the pcl_ros package, you can go to your src folder and type

```
wstool merge http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/pcl_ros
wstool update
```

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, have you looked at wiki.gumstix.org  page? My credential doesn't allow me to post the direct link to it here, but look for "ROS on Turtlecore". The wiki contains an image of Linaro (Ubuntu) running December build of ROS Groovy. It also contains the steps to reproduce the image. There are probably different ways to compile ROS on an Overo, but doing a native seems most simplistic (although it takes time).

---

Originally posted by [Adam YH Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2738/adam-yh-lee/) with karma: 53 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-08**:
Thanks for the reply, I actually started with downloading your image and tried to build the turtlebot stack. This did not work for me, did you get the entire stack to work?
This tutorial uses the rosbuild workspace and not catkin, which we are supposed to use with groovy

**Comment by [Adam YH Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2738/adam-yh-lee/) on 2013-01-25**:
As long as all packages I built in the guide can be built with catkin, it should be fine. I just didn't want to take chances as we are in the transition period. Anyhow, I'm trying to figure out how to best use ROS. Can u elabroate what didnt work?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-25**:
I was able to build all packages from the guide with catkin except irobot_create_2_1 which is not catkinized yet, that was not the problem. I was just thinking there must be an easier way to install the entire turtlebot stack? Did you get that to work? That would be my final goal

**Comment by [Adam YH Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2738/adam-yh-lee/) on 2013-01-26**:
Ah I see. No I haven't played with the turtlebot stack on a Gumstix yet. There are no binaries available for ARM yet, so for now I think we need to compile ourselves.